# Get single result in aggregate - MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this function that return sum of prices for current month

```
const getMonthlyRevenue = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  let month = 1 + moment().month();
  console.log(month);

  const monthly = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $eq: [{ $month: "$createdAt" }, month],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { $month: "$createdAt" },
        price: { $sum: "$price" },
      },
    },
  
  ]);

  res.status(200).json(monthly);
});
```

this function  match only one single document, but result still be a list, so I want get a single document not a list, how can I do that?

Comment: Return the first (and, presumably, only) document in the result set? The output type of `aggregate` is always the same regardless of the number of items in the result set (eg even if using `{ $limit: 1 }`)

Comment: So is there anyway to get the total price for one month?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. What does your aggregation return now and what are you looking for? Currently it looks to me like the pipeline will return up to one document that represents the sum for all documents with a given month of creation (though that can be from different years, eg all docs created in "April" of any year). Sample documents, current output, and desired output would help us better understand your problem and how to help. My first comment is simply stating that the return type of agg will always be a cursor (array-like) regardless of number of results it contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this version will give better performance (assuming you have an index created on `createdAt`). Convert result to an array and use the first element.

```
const monthly = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        createdAt: { 
           $gte: moment().startOf('month').toDate(),
           $lte: moment().endOf('month').toDate()
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { $month: "$createdAt" },
        price: { $sum: "$price" }
      }
    }
]).toArray().shift();
```